# Prime number from 1 to 100 in C

Tags: c

I am writing a program to find prime numbers from 1 to 100. Please check if my code is correct or not. When I am running my code prime numbers are not getting printed. Please help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j, flag, rem;
    flag=0;

    printf("2");
    for(i=3; i<=100; i++)
    {
        for(j=2; j<=i; j++)
        {
            rem = i%j;
            if(rem == 0)
            {
                flag=1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(flag==0)
        {
            printf("%d", i);  
        }
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the output isn't buffering, since you're not printing a `\n` in your output?

Comment: This is a good opportunity to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: @ChrisTurner It's just a broken primality test.

Comment: That sure is a lot of semicolons after the second Hello World.

Comment: Please format your code properly and remove all irrelevant `printf()`s and such before posting. Also, note that you don't have to declare all variables at the top of the outermost block (not even in Dinosaur C), but rather, at worst, the top of the innermost block (in Dinosaur C). Also, think about how you set `flag=1` and then check `flag==0` but never set it back to 0; that's probably not right... But yes, the real answer is to learn how to debug your programs, rather than just dumping them on the internet & asking others to find what you did wrong. You have a better head start than they do.

Comment: Do try and clean up your code before posting. Seeing `;;;` makes me wonder what happened there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of problems

First, the `for(j=2;j<=i;j++)` loop should be `for(j=2;j<i;j++)`, as if j is equal to i, `j % i == 0` will always be true

Second, your flag variable is not doing what you might think it is doing. As HolyBlackCat suggested this is a good opportunity to learn how to use a debugger to see what is happening. You need to reset the flag variable, because once you find a single composite number, your flag will not reset so all following numbers will be flagged as composite. Add:

```
for(i=3;i<=100;i++)
{
    flag = 0;
    for(j=2;j<=i;j++)
    {
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `for (j = 2; j <= i; j++)` to `for (j = 2; j <= i/2; j++)`. You need to loop up to `i/2`.

```
int main()
{
    int i, j, flag, rem;
    printf("2\n");
    for (i = 3; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        flag = 0;
        for (j = 2; j <= i/2; j++)
        {
            if (i % j == 0)
            {
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag == 0)
            printf("%d\n", i);
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is better to have a correct indentation for well-reading purposes. I added some comments in lines where you can optimize your code and I removed the unnecesary 'printf'.  (\t is to write a tab space after what it is printed)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main()
{
    int flag;
    printf("Prime numbers:  2\t");
    for(int i = 3; i <= 100; i++) // You can declare a temporal variable for the cycle
    {
        flag = 0; // reset the flag variable to zero when adding a new number
        for(int j = 2; j < i; j++) 
        {
            if(i%j == 0) // substitute the 'rem' variable for an operation
            {
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(flag == 0) 
        {
            printf("%d\t", i);  
        }
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

The expected output will be:

```
Prime numbers:  2       3       5       7       11
13      17      19      23      29      31      37
41      43      47      53      59      61      67
71      73      79      83      89      97
```

Answer (score 1):

You should reset `flag` at 0 each time you try a new number. Leaving the code like this, as soon as a number isn't prime, the code will never print again.

```
[...snip...]
for(i=3;i<=100;i++)
{
    flag = 0;
    for(j=2;j<=i;j++)
    {
[...snip...]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `flag` is not set/reset correctly. and also there is a lot of scope for improvement in the code.

1. As you already print 2 as prime no so no need to check other even no as 2 is the only even no which is prime.
2. Instead of dividing form `2..n-1` we can check it for `2..n/2`

Find the optimized code below:

```
// return 1 if no is prime else 0
int is_prime(int n)
{
  for(int i = 3; i<= n/2; i+=2){
    if (n%i == 0)
    {
      return 0;
    }
  }
  return 1;
}

int main()
{
  printf("2\n");
  for(int i=3; i<=100; i+=2)
  {
     if (is_prime(i))
    {
      printf("%d\n", i);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```